# $B=\{(x,y):y\geq \frac{1}{x^2}\}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is $B$ closed?

Tags: general-topology

> $B=\{(x,y):y\geq \frac{1}{x^2}\}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, Represent $B$ as a preimage of a continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$,is $B$ closed? Is $B$ connected? Is $B$ compact?

I think the function is $F(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

And I guess it's closed because $B$ is the preimage of $\mathbb{R}$ and the preimage of closed sets is closed, so it is a closed set. But then it is also open, which means there is a non trivial clopen set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not true.

> Not connected

I can take the separation as $U=\{(x,y): x<0\}$ and $V=\{(x,y): x>0\}$.

Then $(U\cap B) \cup (V\cap B)= B$ and $(1,1),(-1,1)$ are in $V,U$ respectively so that are now empty.

$U,V$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $(U\cap B),(V\cap B)$ they are open in $B$ by definition of open in the subspace.

And they are clearly disjoint because $U,V$ are disjoint.

> Compactness

I don't believe it's compact since it's not bounded from above, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Suppose $\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} K_\alpha$ is an open cover.

I need to show there exists a finite subcover.

Comment: Why do you believe $F(B) = \Bbb{R}$?  In particular, is $0$ in $F^{-1}(\Bbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is neither well-defined on $\mathbb R^2$, nor allows you to make conclusions you made.

Instead, consider the continuous function $f:(x,y)=x^2y-1$. Note that $[0,\infty)$ is closed and not compact, and $f^{-1}([0,\infty))=B$.

So, $B$ is not compact and closed.

$B$ is not connected, since the sets $\{(x,y)\mid x<0\}\cap B,\;\{(x,y)\mid x>0\}\cap B$ are open in $B$ by the definition of the subspace topology.

Moreover, these sets are disjoint, and their union is $B$, since when $x=0$, $\frac1{x^2}$ isn't defined.

Comment: That $B$ is not compact can more easily be seen by noting $(1,n)$ is in the set for each natural number $n \ge 1$, so the set is unbounded ( has points with arbitrarily large norm).